# pytorch instance tensor not moved to gpu even with explicit cuda() call

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I'm working on a project where the model requires access to a tensor that i declare in the constructor *init* of the class (im sub-classing torch.nn.Module class)  and then i need to use this tensor in the forward() method via a simple matmul() , the model is sent to gpu via a cuda() call:

```
model = Model()
model.cuda()
```

However when i do forward-propagation of a simple input X through:

```
model(X) # or model.forward(X)
```

I get

> RuntimeError: Expected object of type torch.cuda.FloatTensor but found
>   type torch.FloatTensor for argument #2 'mat2'

Indicating that the second argument of matmul(the instance tensor i declared) is on CPU and it was expected on GPU (as the rest of the model and data).

In matmul, the tensor is transposed via matrix.t()

I even tried overriding the cuda() method thorugh:

```
def cuda(self):
    super().cuda()
    self.matrix.cuda()
```

The data is already in the GPU ,meaning the following line of code was already executed:

```
X = X.cuda()
```

Also the error explcitly says argument 2 of matmul which for this case is the tensor(called matrix) not X.

Comment: `X=X.cuda(); model(X)`?

Comment: forgot  to mention X.cuda() is being executed and the error says argument #2 which is the tensor instead of X, i edited.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume the following:

1. `X` is moved correctly to the GPU
2. The tensor declared in the `Model` class is a simple attribute.

   i.e. Something like the following:

```py
class Model(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.matrix = torch.randn(784, 10)
       
   def forward(self, x):
       return torch.matmul(x, self.matrix)
```

---

If so, your first attempt wouldn't work because the `nn.Module.cuda()` method only moves all of the `Parameters` and `Buffers` to the GPU.

You would need to make `Model.matrix` a [`Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Parameter) instead of regular attribute.
Wrap it in the parameter class.
Something like:

```py
self.matrix = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(784, 10))
```

Now, instead of automatically casting to the GPU like above, you tried to manually call the `.cuda()` method on `Model.matrix` within the override.

This doesn't work either because of a subtle difference between the [`nn.Module.cuda()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.cuda) method and the [`torch.Tensor.cuda()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.cuda) method.

While `nn.Module.cuda()` moves all the `Parameters` and `Buffers` of the `Module` to GPU and returns itself, `torch.Tensor.cuda()` only returns a **copy** of the tensor on the GPU.

The original tensor is unaffected.

---

In summary, either:

1. Wrap your `matrix` attribute as a `Parameter` or
2. Assign the GPU copy back to matrix via:

```py
self.matrix = self.matrix.cuda()
```

In your override.

I would suggest the first.

Answer (score 8):

I would like to highlight this from @Vaisakh's answer:

> While nn.Module.cuda() moves all the Parameters and Buffers of the Module to GPU and returns itself, torch.Tensor.cuda() ***only returns a copy of the tensor*** on the GPU.

In other words, as @Umang_Gupta says in his comment:

```
# if m is a Module, you do:
m.cuda()

# if t is a Tensor, you do:
t = t.cuda()
```